# how to get a particular column value from a list view on click of a row from that list view?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view where in i have four to five columns. The values to the list view are assigned through a database query. The list view is created using SimpleCursorAdapter. I am trying to get the value of the first column of the list view... but m not able to retrieve it. How do i do that??? 
Here's my custom adapter

```
private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to,int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     @Override 
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

       //get reference to the row
       View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       //check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
       if(position % 2 == 0){ 
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
       }
       else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
       }
       return view; 
      } 


}
```

here is where i am assigning my adapter to the listview

```
MyCursorAdapter myDataAdapter=new MyCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_row_layout,cursor, columns, to, 0);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null, false));

    listView.setAdapter(myDataAdapter);
```

and here is the onclick listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //View view= 
            String ttsl_can=(( listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));
            Toast.makeText(PendingActivity.this, ttsl_can, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

by clicking on a particular row of the listview m getting the response as **android.database.SQLiteCursor@40d2f13d**

how do i get the response as the value of the first column on which ever row i click???
what change do i have make in my code to achieve that???

Please Help!! Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You should be add either list or array data with adapter

Comment: got error??? put logcat for correct solution

Comment: @PratikButani no i dint get any logcat error

Comment: @sunil cursor is data coming from the database to be assigned to the list

Comment: get the data from the cursor and add into list and set with adapter this list do not set the cursor

Comment: @shivani if answer is useful then please do upvote.

Comment: Thank you @shivani Contact if other problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out like this:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Cursor cursor = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Here you have to getString using index
            String str = cursor.getString(<you column index>);

            Toast.makeText(PendingActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not Working, How to rebuild?